# what is uri in SOAP non wsdl mode options

Tags: web-services, soap

php SOAPClient and SOAPServer in non wsdl mode require an array of options.
the location in options used to point where is the web service server file
but what do the uri in options?? because i change it to every thing and the web server is work fine

```
$options = array(
'uri' => 'http://aahshhs.com',   //wath do this line?????
'location' => 'http://localhost/exer/Server.php',);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array of options. If working in WSDL mode, this parameter is optional. If working in non-WSDL mode, the location and uri options must be set, where:

- **location** is the URL of the SOAP server to send the request to
- **uri** is the target namespace of the SOAP service.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.construct.php